# What is the Simplest Tomcat/Apache Connector (Windows)?

Tags: windows, apache, tomcat, connector

I have apache 2.2 and tomcat 5.5 running on a Windows XP machine.

Which tomcat/apache connector is the easiest to set up and is well documented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mod_proxy_ajp` would be the easiest to use if you are using Apache 2.2. It is part of the Apache distribution so you don't need to install any additional software.

In your `httpd.conf` you need to make sure that `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_ajp` are loaded:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
```

Then you can use the [ProxyPass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) and [ProxyPassReverse](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) directives as follows:

```
ProxyPass /portal ajp://localhost:8009/portal
ProxyPassReverse /portal ajp://localhost:8009/portal
```

You should consult the Apache 2.2 documentation for a full catalog of the directives available.

Comment: In addition, ensure that your tomcat server.xml configuration has the AJP connector defined/uncommented. E.g. <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />

Comment: @JamieLove Seems to be enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

`mod_jk`, or simply just use `mod_proxy` even though it's not really a Tomcat connector.